# How to send a JSONArray message to a device using GCM from php server?

Tags: php, android, json, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a notification to the device. I can send normal string message bu I wonder if it is possible to send JSONArray message and if it is possible how can I parse this message on the device?

Thanks, İsmail.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's possible to send JSON array. There is no difference in sending text/JSON, as both of them are texts.
2. You could parse it in the mobile easily using a simple parser. Follow [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/). It helps you parsing JSON easily.